# React component design

Tags: reactjs

I'm porting a small script over to React. It's a simple country-region-selector plugin that ties together a country dropdown and a region dropdown, so the latter always shows the relevant regions for the selected country. See: https://github.com/benkeen/country-region-selector

Thing is, I can't quite fathom the best way to componentize this using React. I need the two key elements (the country dropdown and the region dropdown) to be completely independent, so a user can choose exactly where the two dropdowns appear in the DOM + the surrounding markup. But I want all the inner-workings (i.e. how the two components are tied together) to be hidden from view. I was thinking maybe something like this...

```
<CountryRegions>
   <span>arbitrary markup here</span>
   <CountryDropdown />
   <p>
       <RegionDropdown />
   </p>
</CountryRegions>
```

... but I'm hazy on how the actual implementation of that would work. Any ideas / better suggestions? Hope this question is clear.

Comment: Are you saying you want your country selector to be two React components that might both exist within HTML (ie two `ReactDOM.render()` calls), or the whole app is React and you want the components to exist anywhere in the app?

Comment: Not sure I quite follow... basically I don't want users to have to wire the two dropdowns together. e.g. maintain the selected state of the country dropdown + pass that value to the region dropdown. Instead, I'd like to allow users to just include that single <CountryRegions /> component, containing the two dropdowns in whatever markup they want. That'd make the component really easy to "drop-in" into a React application.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like the components exist in the same React application, I just wasn't sure if you were saying you wanted React elements mixed in a traditional HTML page within separate HTML containers.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Yeah, same app - all in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share *something* between components using [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). Basically **CountryRegions** component will provide a context that every child can use.

**CountryDropdown** and **RegionDropdown** can use the provided context as long as they are child of **CountryRegions** component, no matter how deeply nested.

Comment: Excellent, thanks nvartolomei. Yeah, that looks like it'll fit the bill!